# Spring TransactionalTemplate does not roll back on exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

### Problem Statement

**My goal is to:**

1. Read CSV file row --> Convert to DTO object (*This step is not related to my question, included for the sake of completeness*)
2. Collect 'n' DTO objects --> Call save()/update() service methods. (*Under the same transactional context*)

**Expected:** When one save()/update() call fails --> Rollback the whole batch.

**Actual:** When one save()/update() call fails --> Spring commits the record for previous call(s).

### Implementation

Below is my code implementation. (*Omitted helper methods and non-relevant attributes for brevity*)

**Importer Class:**

> Groups List(Patient) and calls save()/update() depending upon the operation type.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

import com.github.swapnil.hims.bo.importer.BulkImporter;
import com.github.swapnil.hims.bo.importer.Importer;
import com.github.swapnil.hims.dto.PatientDetail;
import com.github.swapnil.hims.service.PatientService;

@Component
public class PatientImporter extends Importer implements BulkImporter {
    @Autowired
    private PatientService patientSvc;

    private final TransactionTemplate txTmpl;

    public PatientImporter(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.txTmpl = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    }

    @Override
    public PatientDetail rowToObject(CSVRecord record) {
        // Convert row to DTO object.
        return patientDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveToDb(List<Object> patients) {
        List<PatientDetail> patientList = patients.stream().map(patient -> (PatientDetail) patient)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        saveAll(patientList, this.importType, BATCH_SIZE);
    }

    private void saveAll(List<PatientDetail> patients, Importer.Type action, Integer batchSize) {
        txTmpl.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                createPatients(patients, action, batchSize);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createPatients(List<PatientDetail> patients, Importer.Type action, Integer batchSize) {
        int startAt = 0;
        while (true) {
            List<PatientDetail> patientBatch = patients.stream().skip(startAt).limit(batchSize)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            for (PatientDetail patient : patientBatch) {
                if (action == Importer.Type.CREATE) {
                    patientSvc.save(patient);
                } else {
                    patientSvc.update(patient);
                }
            }

            if (patientBatch.size() != batchSize) {
                break;
            }

            startAt += batchSize;
        }
    }
}
```

**PatientService Class:**

> Repository/Service class for Patient.

```java
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.github.swapnil.hims.dao.PatientDao;
import com.github.swapnil.hims.dto.PatientDetail;
import com.github.swapnil.hims.entities.Patient;
import com.github.swapnil.hims.exception.PatientException;
import com.github.swapnil.hims.service.PatientService;

@Service
public class PatientServiceImpl implements PatientService {
    private final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(PatientServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private PatientDao patientDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(PatientDetail patientDetail) {
        patientDao.save(getPatient(patientDetail));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(Long id, PatientDetail patientDetail) {
        patientDao.save(getPatient(id, patientDetail));
    }

    @Override
    public void update(PatientDetail patientDetail) {
        update(patientDetail.getIdentifier(), patientDetail);
    }

    private Patient getPatient(PatientDetail patientDetail) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(patientDetail.getPatientId())) {
            throw new PatientException("Patient ID is required!");
        }

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(patientDetail.getName())) {
            throw new PatientException("Patient name is required!");
        }

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(patientDetail.getEmail())) {
            throw new PatientException("Patient e-mail is required!");
        }

        Patient dbPatient = patientDao.findByPatientId(patientDetail.getPatientId());
        if (dbPatient != null) {
            throw new PatientException(String.format("Patient with the same pid '%s' already exists!", dbPatient.getPatientId()));
        }

        return patientDetail.toPatient();
    }

    private Patient getPatient(Long id, PatientDetail patientDetail) {
        Patient patient = patientDao.findById(id);

        if (patient == null) {
            throw new PatientException("Patient with id " + id + " does not exists.");
        }

        patient.setName(StringUtils.isEmpty(patientDetail.getName()) ? patient.getName() : patientDetail.getName());
        patient.setCity(StringUtils.isEmpty(patientDetail.getCity()) ? patient.getCity() : patientDetail.getCity());
        patient.setAddress(StringUtils.isEmpty(patientDetail.getAddress()) ? patient.getAddress() : patientDetail.getAddress());
        patient.setEmail(StringUtils.isEmpty(patientDetail.getEmail()) ? patient.getEmail() : patientDetail.getEmail());
        patient.setContactNumber(patientDetail.getContactNumber() != null ? patient.getContactNumber() : patientDetail.getContactNumber());
        patient.setPatientId(StringUtils.isEmpty(patientDetail.getPatientId()) ? patient.getPatientId() : patientDetail.getPatientId());

        return patient;
    }
}
```

**PatientDao.java**

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.github.swapnil.hims.entities.Patient;

public interface PatientDao extends JpaRepository<Patient, String> {
    public Patient findById(Long id);

    public void deleteById(Long id);

    public Patient findByPatientId(String patientId);
}
```

**I tried:**

- `try {createPatients(patients, action, batchSize);} catch() {status.setRollbackOnly()}`
- Setting PropagationBehaviour to PROPAGATION_REQUIRED.

I cannot understand what I'm missing here, I've invested loads of time in solving this and would really, really appreciate any help. I'm using MySQL v8.0.16.

*(GitHub repo [URL](https://github.com/Swapnil-ingle/hospital-hims-app))*

#### EDIT

While debugging, I found that `Patient dbPatient = patientDao.findByPatientId(patientDetail.getPatientId());` call causes the hibernate to flush the session and commit the previous object to DB. I'm not sure how to prevent this though. I tried some things but didn't work, I'll keep looking and update this.

Comment: Are there any exceptions logged if `save()/update()` throw exception ?

Comment: Yes, a runtime exception is thrown and logged.

```Error while bulk-importing patients...
com.github.swapnil.hims.exception.PatientException: Patient with the same pid 'PID_HINIC_1' already exists!
 at com.github.swapnil.hims.service.impl.PatientServiceImpl.getPatient(PatientServiceImpl.java:85)
 at com.github.swapnil.hims.service.impl.PatientServiceImpl.save(PatientServiceImpl.java:43)
 at com.github.swapnil.hims.service.impl.PatientServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c348e5ac.invoke(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)```

Comment: *call causes the hibernate to flush the session and commit the previous object to DB*. Flushing and commit are not the same thing. On flush the SQL is sent to the database however no commit takes place until the transaction completes.

Comment: Why are you mixing manual transactions with Spring's transactional annotations? Annotate saveToDB with `@Transactional` and remove the `txTmpl.execute(...)` as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: Yes, ideally it should've flushed and not committed. However, from the log messages, it says that it first flush and then inserts the object and then the ```findByPatientId()``` is invoked. Please see the log [messages](https://gist.github.com/Swapnil-ingle/8f5ef8ae1c3d392ade5cfcee417d701d).

Comment: >> Why are you mixing manual transactions with Spring's transactional annotations? 

@AlanHay, Yeah I tried that. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't use @Transactional like this :

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public yourFunctionThatHasAllOperations() {
    // do your logic here
}
```

Comment: By default, ```@Transactional``` annotation rolls back for RuntimeException.class and the ```save()/update()``` method here throws PatientException (a RuntimeException). I tried your solution anyway, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to rollback the whole batch, you need to annotate the 'saveToDb' method in Patient importer with @Transactional as well.

Comment: You're saying the whole batch processing should fall under the same transaction-block, right?

I tried that but it didn't work. I think because I'm already providing a transactional context in ```protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) { ... }``` method which already encapsulates the whole batch processing. So, I don't think that's the problem here.